# Cannot join two working SQL queries with UNION

Tags: mysql

I wonder why there is an error. Maybe because of the `NULL`? Both queries work individualy but fail when unioned:

```
select A.id,A.Name, B.Grade from Students A, Grades B 
where A.Marks>=B.min_mark and A.marks<=B.max_mark and B.grade>=8 
order by B.grade desc,A.name
union
select A.id,null, B.Grade from Students A, Grades B 
where A.Marks>=B.min_mark and A.marks<=B.max_mark and B.grade<8 
order by B.grade asc,A.name
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near 'union

The original assignement was

> Ketty gives Eve a task to generate a report containing three columns:
> Name, Grade and Mark. Ketty doesn't want the NAMES of those students
> who received a grade lower than 8. The report must be in descending
> order by grade -- i.e. higher grades are entered first. If there is
> more than one student with the same grade (8-10) assigned to them,
> order those particular students by their name alphabetically. Finally,
> if the grade is lower than 8, use "NULL" as their name and list them
> by their grades in descending order. If there is more than one student
> with the same grade (1-7) assigned to them, order those particular
> students by their marks in ascending order.

Is there an other way than the `union`?

Comment: Add your table structure in question.

Comment: You could use If statement : https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-function.php. So instead of union, make a if statement on name column. Like:
select A.id,IF(B.grade>=8, A.Name, null), B.Grade from  Students A, Grades B where A.Marks>=B.min_mark and A.marks<=B.max_mark and B.grade>=8 order by B.grade desc,A.name

Comment: Try using `order by` in last SQL query only [UNION](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=union-order-by-clause)

Comment: The problem is that the assignment asks to have an opposite ordering for both subqueries. So neither solution would work.

Comment: Ok, I ignored the instructions about order and the result was accepted. So there was a bug in the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in MySQL manual regarding the use of ORDER BY and LIMIT clause in statement using union,*to apply an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to an individual SELECT, parenthesize the SELECT and place the clause inside the parentheses.* Try this:

```
(select A.id,A.Name, B.Grade from Students A, Grades B where A.Marks>=B.min_mark and A.marks<=B.max_mark and B.grade>=8 order by B.grade desc,A.name)
union
(select A.id,null, B.Grade from Students A, Grades B where A.Marks>=B.min_mark and A.marks<=B.max_mark and B.grade<8 order by B.grade asc,A.name);
```

Besides , only the ORDER BY of the last query in the union takes effect.